# Proxies.json overwritten by publish; where should it reside?

Tags: azure-functions

I'm exploring the use of Azure Proxies in my Function app. I started out testing the proxy configuration online in the web portal which creates a `proxies.json` file online.

In Visual Studio 2017 I have a project with a single .cs file containing multiple functions which are published to Azure using a 'web deploy' method. They are defined by using the `[FunctionName("NameOfFunction")]` attribute syntax.

Looking at the documentation, it would seem I need to define a `proxies.json` file locally so it gets published along with my functions. The problem is...I don't know where this file is supposed to reside.

I've tried placing it on the root of my project files but when I deploy it doesn't get picked up online in Azure (proxies are blank). Is it possible to define a local `proxies.json` and publish it along with my web deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to define a local `proxies.json` and publish it along with my web deploy?

**Yes**, put the `proxies.json` next to your `host.json` which is located in the root of a function app directory. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#advanced-configuration).

And right click the `proxies.json` and choose the `Properties`. 
Set the **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy if newer**. So that it will upload proxies.json and overwrite the file on Azure when you deploy.

[image]

Comment: BINGO! That was it. I added the file afterward and didn't check that option. Cheers.